# How do I deploy versioned releases using cmake and git?

Tags: git, cmake

My project uses git for version control, and cmake for the build/install process. 
When i want to release my project for other devs to use, i'll typically `git tag x.y`, followed by `make install` to a directory (set using CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX), let's call it `/tmp/release`.

I'd like to automate/combine this process, so that any time i attempt to install, cmake adds a git tag by incrementing the minor (minors at 99 rollover to 0, and the major is incremented), pushes the tag to remote, and then installs to `/tmp/release/x.y`

i.e, 5.67 - > 5.68 and 5.99 -> 6.00

This sounds like it should be possible, but i'm having trouble connecting the dots and making this cohesive.

Any suggestions on modules that already exist to do this, or writing this from scratch?

Comment: CMake is to find dependencies and create a build system. What you want to do is better made with a bash script or similar.